# 10Gb ethernet between two computers

Tags: networking, ethernet, 10gbit

**I've edited this question to prevent it from being downvoted and/or closed**

What kind of cable will allow a direct connection between two computers with 10Gb Ethernet. I see there are a few choices (at least copper and fibre). How would one determine the right cable and connector type? Is there anything else one should know when dealing with 10Gb cards that's different from typical 1Gb Ethernet?

I am NOT asking for recommendations on brands or types of technology. (this comment was always here)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar question on serverfault.com related to RedHat server, that might be helpful: [switchless Infiniband between two servers on RHEL 6.3](https://serverfault.com/questions/451362/switchless-infiniband-between-two-servers-on-rhel-6-3)

Comment: Thanks that gives me a little help if I go the infiniband direction.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin No problem.  Glad I could provide some help